# What does "the top line numbers let on." mean in a context

Tags: verbs

Reading [**this article**](https://www.yahoo.com/finance/news/student-loan-forgiveness-10000-by-us-state-162447346.html), there is a line,

> Preston Cooper, a visiting fellow at the center-right think tank Foundation for Research and Economic Opportunity, noted that student loan borrowers in states "where blue-collar industries are more dominant... are more likely to have taken it on to get a certificate or an associate's degree [as opposed to a bachelors degree and potentially graduate school], so the average borrower has a lot less debt."

> That said, Cooper added, states where more citizens pursue college degrees "will benefit more from the $10,000 cancellation than **the top line numbers let on.**" This is highlighted by the map above: While roughly 49,000 Wyomingites would see relief from $10,000 in forgiveness, nearly 1 million borrowers in Virginia would benefit.

What would the bold part possibly mean?

I appreciate your help very much.

Comment: Hi, Kentaro - did you look up the phrase ["let on"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/let-on)?

Comment: @stangdon I'm sorry I didn't since I thought there would be many definitions. It looks like I am completely wrong, would you kindly make an answer instead?

Comment: No worries!  You are correct that **let** has many, many meanings.  It just happens that "let on" is a specific phrase with its own meaning.

Comment: @stangdon Thank you. And what would the "top line numbers" mean here then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Top line**](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/topline.asp) or **top line number** mean "The overall amount of gain or loss."  This term comes from corporate income statements, where the gross revenue is reported on the top line of the statement.  In a metaphorical sense, it means something like "the big picture" or "the general picture without details".

To [**let on**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/let-on) means to reveal knowledge, or suggest that you know something.  You use it like "Grandfather *let on* that he was planning to retire this year."

In the way that the speaker is using these two phrases together, they mean something like

> states where more citizens pursue college degrees will benefit more from the $10,000 cancellation than **just the number ($10,000) by itself would suggest.**

The $10,000 is the *top line number*, because that's the obvious number that you see, but it is not the real benefit.